# How to assign a bitmap to TSpeedButton in Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I am trying to assign a bitmap to a speedbutton in FMX Delphi. In design time, I create a TImageList, load my image and then assign one to the speedbutton.

How do I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

```
var
  Size: TSizeF;
begin
  Size := TSize.Create(64,64)
  Bitmap1.Assign(Imagelist1.Bitmap(Size, Index));
end
```

Comment: nolaspeaker thanks for this. But how do I load bitmap1 in a speedbutton?

Comment: The Speedbutton has a .Imageindex property, you just choose one in the property editor AFTER you have assigned the .Images property of the SpeedButton. (just like in VCL)

Comment: nolaspeaker, I am sorry I can't see how your code can work. If I want to do the whole thing programmatically, I need to create an ImageList, load a bitmap, then assign the imagelist to the speedbutton and then choose the which image to display in the speedbutton. This is what I need to do. Your code assigned an image to a bitmap from an imagelist

Comment: Since the advent of the Imagelist in Delphi, you can't _assign_ a Tbitmap to a TSpeedbutton. But you _can_ parent a TImage to the Speedbutton and use the Timage.Bitmap.x properties to get your image from anywhere. TImage.Bitmap is a TBitmap, so you could .LoadfromFile if you like. Or you could use my code to assign to it from a design-time image list.

Comment: Setting the parent property worked. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

In the TSpeedButton you should set Images and ImageIndex.
To load pictures into TImageList you can use [AddOrSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.ImgList.TCustomImageList.AddOrSet)
or you can use this example

```
procedure TForm11.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  SourceName = 'Картинка';
  procedure LoadPicture(const Source: TCustomSourceItem; const Scale: Single; const FileName: string);
  var
    BitmapItem: TCustomBitmapItem;
    TmpBitmap: TBitmap;
  begin
    BitmapItem := Source.MultiResBitmap.ItemByScale(Scale, True, True);
    if BitmapItem = nil then
    begin
      BitmapItem := Source.MultiResBitmap.Add;
      BitmapItem.Scale := Scale;
    end;
    BitmapItem.FileName := FileName;
    TmpBitmap := BitmapItem.CreateBitmap;
    try
      if TmpBitmap <> nil then
        BitmapItem.Bitmap.Assign(TmpBitmap);
    finally
      TmpBitmap.Free;
    end;
  end;
var
  NewSource: TCustomSourceItem;
  NewDestination: TCustomDestinationItem;
  NewLayer: TLayer;
begin
  if ImageList1.Source.IndexOf(SourceName) = -1 then
  begin
    NewSource := ImageList1.Source.Add;
    NewSource.Name := SourceName;
    NewSource.MultiResBitmap.TransparentColor := TColorRec.Fuchsia;
    NewSource.MultiResBitmap.SizeKind := TSizeKind.Custom;
    NewSource.MultiResBitmap.Width := 16;
    NewSource.MultiResBitmap.Height := 16;
    LoadPicture(NewSource, 1, 'D:\Мои веселые картинки\Icons\16x16\alarm16.bmp');
    LoadPicture(NewSource, 1.5, 'D:\Мои веселые картинки\Icons\24x24\alarm24.bmp');
    NewDestination := ImageList1.Destination.Add;
    NewLayer := NewDestination.Layers.Add;
    NewLayer.SourceRect.Rect := TRectF.Create(TPoint.Zero, NewSource.MultiResBitmap.Width,
      NewSource.MultiResBitmap.Height);
    NewLayer.Name := SourceName;
    ControlAction1.ImageIndex := NewDestination.Index;
  end;
end;
```